# Bring argument from one class to another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working through a course on Codecademy, I'm stuck on a project focusing on OOP. I need to pass the items argument in the Menu init to the Franchise class. I'm trying to have available_menu() take in a time parameter and return the menus available for that time. So if i put 12 noon, it would return brunch and kids. Right now if I try to access the info in any of the menus through the Franchise class, I'm getting the repr from Menu, not the arguments. Not sure how to go about this problem.

Thanks!

```
class Menu:
  def __init__(self, name, items, start_time, end_time):
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
    self.start_time = start_time
    self.end_time = end_time

  def __repr__(self):
    return "{name} starts at {start_time} and ends at {end_time}".format(name = self.name, start_time = self.start_time, end_time = self.end_time)

  def calculate_bill(self, purchased_items):
    self.purchased_items = purchased_items
    bill = 0
    temp_item = []

    for item in purchased_items:
      if item in self.items:
        temp_item.append(self.items[item])
      else:
        print("That's not on the menu")

    for item in temp_item:
      bill += item
    return bill

class Franchise:

  def __init__(address, menus):
    self.address = address
    self.menus = menus

  def available_menu(self):
    for item in self.items:

brunch = Menu("Brunch", {'pancakes': 7.50, 'waffles': 9.00, 'burger': 11.00, 'home fries': 4.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00, 'tea': 1.00, 'mimosa': 10.50, 'orange juice': 3.50}, 11, 16)

early_bird = Menu("Early Bird", {'salumeria plate': 8.00, 'salad and breadsticks (serves 2, no refills)': 14.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 9.00, 'duck ragu': 17.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00}, 15, 18)

dinner = Menu("Dinner", {'crostini with eggplant caponata': 13.00, 'ceaser salad': 16.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 11.00, 'duck ragu': 19.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 2.00, 'espresso': 3.00}, 17, 23)

kids = Menu("Kids", {'chicken nuggets': 6.50, 'fusilli with wild mushrooms': 12.00, 'apple juice': 3.00}, 11, 21)


flag_ship_store = Franchise("1232 West End Road", [brunch, early_bird, dinner, kids])

new_installment = Franchise("12 East Mulberry Street", [brunch, early_bird, dinner, kids])
```

Comment: The format of your code is wrong (the for-loop in the Franchise class). Fix it please. Also when you ask such questions, you should point to the exact place in your code that you are experiencing problems with and what the problem is. Alternatively, you can provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: right now you have an IndentationError in `available_menu`

Comment: The example should be complete. Right now only you know what the problem is. If someone copies your code to run it, they will get many errors that probably do not relate to the problem you just described.

Comment: I gotcha @smac89 still new to this whole world so I'm still picking up little things like that! Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a specific menu's items in `available_menu` rather than just `self.items` which doesn't exist in the franchise class. This adjusted example prints out all the menu items for the first menu given to `flag_ship_store`.

```
class Franchise:
  def __init__(self, address, menus):
    self.address = address
    self.menus = menus

  def available_menu(self, menu):
    for item in menu.items:
        print(item)

brunch = Menu("Brunch", {'pancakes': 7.50, 'waffles': 9.00, 'burger': 11.00, 'home fries': 4.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00, 'tea': 1.00, 'mimosa': 10.50, 'orange juice': 3.50}, 11, 16)
early_bird = Menu("Early Bird", {'salumeria plate': 8.00, 'salad and breadsticks (serves 2, no refills)': 14.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 9.00, 'duck ragu': 17.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 1.50, 'espresso': 3.00}, 15, 18)
dinner = Menu("Dinner", {'crostini with eggplant caponata': 13.00, 'ceaser salad': 16.00, 'pizza with quattro formaggi': 11.00, 'duck ragu': 19.50, 'mushroom ravioli (vegan)': 13.50, 'coffee': 2.00, 'espresso': 3.00}, 17, 23)
kids = Menu("Kids", {'chicken nuggets': 6.50, 'fusilli with wild mushrooms': 12.00, 'apple juice': 3.00}, 11, 21)

flag_ship_store = Franchise("1232 West End Road", [brunch, early_bird, dinner, kids])
new_installment = Franchise("12 East Mulberry Street", [brunch, early_bird, dinner, kids])
flag_ship_store.available_menu(flag_ship_store.menus[0])
```

Comment: That outputs:
pancakes
waffles
burger
home fries
coffee
espresso
tea
mimosa
orange juice. I need it to output the times at the end, the two integers for each menu after the actual menu items. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, you would just add `print(menu.start_time)` and `print(menu.end_time)` to the end of `available_menu` (don't nest it in the for loop though).